# Search View not starting searchable activity and not finding searchable configuration

Tags: android, xml, searchview

I've been following this tutorial http://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html and also checking in Stackoverflow but I can't find the solution y guess both problems are related.

Here is my searchable.xml under xml folder in res:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:label="@string/app_name"
           android:hint="@string/search_hint" >
</searchable>
```

This is my menu with the search button:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="@string/search_title"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
```

Here I associate the searchable configuration:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager =
            (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    return true;
}
```

This is the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:name=".MainApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
        android:value=".activities.SearchResultsActivity"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.SearchResultsActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
    </activity>
</application>
```

With this code I get the user interface working but it doesn't start the searchable activity and it doesn't associate the searchable configuration, here is how it looks after compiling:

[image]

As you can see the user interface seems to work, I already checked that the names in searchable.xml are string resources, i added

```
<meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
        android:value=".activities.SearchResultsActivity"/>
```

which isn't in the Google tutorial, I don't know what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution, I had to use the fully qualified class name instead of `.activities.SearchResultsActivity`

Comment: i did the change in the manifest file and it worked. thank you

Answer (score 0):

The fully qualified name didn't make it work for me. For me, the fix was to ensure the following:

1. Setting a [new ComponentName](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20172017/6411857) with `applicationContext` and the "Searchable Activity"
2. The `searchable` meta-data tag goes on the "Searchable Activity", not the Activity that has the `SearchView` like the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/search/setup) state.
3. Making sure your `searchable.xml` has both a `label` and a `hint` at a minimum